# Looking for a way to solve this differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody give me a hint how to try to solve the following differential equation:

$ \ddot{r} - \frac{1}{r^3} = 1$

where $r = r(t)$ and $\ddot{r}$ is the second derivative.
It is not homework btw.
This is the case of a physical particle in a centripetal force field, where the force is constant over all distances.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $\dot{r}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ddot{r}-\dfrac{1}{r^3}=1$

$\ddot{r}=1+\dfrac{1}{r^3}$

$\dot{r}\ddot{r}=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{r^3}\right)\dot{r}$

$\int\dot{r}\ddot{r}~dt=\int\left(1+\dfrac{1}{r^3}\right)\dot{r}~dt$

$\int\dot{r}~d\dot{r}=\int\left(1+\dfrac{1}{r^3}\right)dr$

$\dfrac{\dot{r}^2}{2}=r-\dfrac{1}{2r^2}+c$

$\dot{r}^2=\dfrac{2r^3+c_1r^2-1}{r^2}$

$\dot{r}=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{2r^3+c_1r^2-1}}{r}$

$\dfrac{dr}{dt}=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{2r^3+c_1r^2-1}}{r}$

$dt=\pm\dfrac{r}{\sqrt{2r^3+c_1r^2-1}}dr$

$t=\pm\int^r\dfrac{r}{\sqrt{2r^3+c_1r^2-1}}dr+c_2$